# What does assignment of literal to method/function mean in PHP?

Tags: php

I’m writing some code using PHP 5.5, and while writing I mistakenly wrote assignment instead of passing argument to methods, like below:

```
$user->setPostCnt = 0;
$user->setAdmin = false;
```

where it should be of course:

```
$user->setPostCnt(0);
$user->setAdmin(false);
```

And PHP, while parsing it, didn’t return any errors or warnings. Because of it I found problem (both parameters being null) much much later and I thought there is a bug in library I was using (ie. I was sure, while doing some data operations, library interprets both `0` and `false` as `null`).

**So, what does this type of assignment:**

```
$object->methodName = value;
```

**mean in PHP?**

Comment: You're just creating new properties :)

Comment: Without a concrete example we can only guess. It *probably* is just assigning a value to a member variable that has the same name as a method.

Comment: Then you're just assigning to a previously undefined property. Methods and variables live in distinct namespaces. (Occasionally it might invoke `__set`, and with a more hybrid implementation another method; but probably not in your case). Nothing here is PHP 5.5 specific, btw.

Comment: Oh, I didn’t know PHP can create new properties at any moment. I’m PHP noob. Well, thank you for answers. :)

Answer (score 1):

What do I understand that when you use

`$object->methodName = value;`

means you're accessing/assigning a property/variable of the class while

`$user->setPostCnt(0);
$user->setAdmin(false);`

means you're acessing a method/function of the class

Comment: Yeah, I know this. But this property doesn’t exist. I didn’t know PHP would create this property “on the fly” in this context.

Comment: @silmeth PHP creates every variable that way!

Comment: Yeah, as I said I’m PHP noob and I’m too used to C++ classes ;-). Still cannot entirely understand dynamically created variables in my mind. :)